# Database query returns strange values for display in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having a hard time again in my query for codeigniter. First of all I read about this tutorials to base the work I'm doing in current: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html

Now what I do is something like this for the model function for my database:

```
public function get_events()
    {
            $id = $this->session->userdata('id');
            $this->db->flush_cache();
            $this->db->select('event_id');
            $this->db->select('event_name');
            $this->db->select('event_date');
            $this->db->select('event_time');
            $this->db->select('event_count');
            $this->db->select('event_max');
            $this->db->select('status');
            $query = $this->db->get_where('event_details',array('bar_id' => $id));
            return $query->row_array();
    }
```

And now to pass the values in my controller I use this line of code:

```
$data['events'] = $this->events_model->get_events();
```

And for the view I use this:

```
<table class="events_list">
<?php foreach ($events as $events_info): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $events_info['id'] ?>">
            <?php echo $events_info['event_name'] ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $events_info['event_date'] ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $events_info['event_time'] ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $events_info['event_count'].'/'.$events_info['event_max'] ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $events_info['status'] ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

I'm supposed to get a return of:

```
(hidden)1 | Silverstein Concert | 2012-07-11 | 18:00:00 | 0/500 | 1
```

but instead I get a return of

```
1 | 1 | 1 | 1/1 | 1
```

Well I haven't displayed the whole return but this is supposed to have a 7 rows which all has a strange 1 character returns (next row contains full of S). I can't tell where the problem really is since when I use

```
$data['test']=$data['events']['event_name'];
```

in my controller and displays it on my view  the event name displays but only the first row data is repeating 7 times. Well I just need to solve this so that I can move on. Thanks!

Comment: If you can get the event name using `$data['events']['event_name']`, it means `$data[events]` contains a single row. Remove the `foreach` from your view and try with `$events['event_name']`, `$events['event_date']` etc.

Comment: what do you get when you write print_r($events) before foreach ?

Comment: oh wait I'll try your suggestions. :)

Comment: Oh you're both correct I only get 1 row. Array ( [event_id] => 16 [event_name] => Silverstein Concert [event_date] => 2012-07-11 [event_time] => 18:00:00 [event_count] => 0 [event_max] => 500 [status] => 1 ). But well it's supposed to return 7 rows. How does this happen?

Comment: Check the [`row_array`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) documentation.

Comment: oh wait! I already got it. it's because I use row_array(); instead of result_array();

Comment: air4x , please add your comment as an answer since it helped me the most to realize that something is wrong so that I can check it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get the event name using `$data['events']['event_name']`, it means `$data[events]` contains a single row. Remove the `foreach` from your view and try with `$events['event_name']`, `$events['event_date']` etc.

[`row_array`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) returns only a single row from your result set.